# when apply word2vec just characters shown not a word ؟

Tags: python, nlp, text-mining, word2vec

this my code you can see i am tokonize the sentence to word but i am still have a problem when i apply 
word2vec model in my sentences i use Arabic text 
anaconda version 4.7.12

```
sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(str(sentences1))
sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
for i in range(len(sentences)):
sentences[i] = [word for word in sentences[i] if word not in stopwords.words('arabic')]

sentences = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',(str(sentences)))
sentences = re.sub("\d+", "", sentences)
sentences =sentences.strip()
sentences = nltk.word_tokenize(sentences)
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
model = Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1)
words1 = model.wv.vocab
```

in words1 the vocab just shown the letters

Answer (score 0):

Your tokenization & preprocessing looks a bit confused. After word-tokenizing at the top, you turn it all back into a giant string again on the line...

```
sentences = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',(str(sentences)))
```

Performing another word-tokenization on that string still just leaves you with a single list where each item is simple words – which means each supposed 'sentence' is now just one word, so it's a list of characters per 'sentence' rather than a list of words.

I suggest string-based cleanup on the strings before word-tokenization, and only word-tokenize as a final step. And, verify that `sentences` has the required format before passing to `Word2Vec`. For example, if you were to execute:

```
print(str(iter(sentences).next())
```

You should see the first item in `sentences`, which should be a list-of-words, not just a string. (If it's just a string, you'll see the symptom you've seen – where `Word2Vec` only learned individual characters.)

Comment: thank you so much for replay i used these code: you can consider the sentence_string its a list for sentences and i toknize the word by the code                           tokenized_sents = [word_tokenize(i) for i in sentences_strings_ted]